# Removing url trailing forward slash ASP.NET Webforms, IIS7

Tags: c#, webforms, iis-7

I am maintaining an existing ASP.NET Webforms application. An issue has arisen where we now need to guarantee that the trailing slash is removed from all URL's

```
 https://www.example.com/blah.aspx --> https://www.example.com/blah.aspx
 https://www.example.com/blah --> https://www.example.com/blah
 https://www.example.com/blah/ --> https://www.example.com/blah 
 https://www.example.com/blah/?a=1 --> https://www.example.com/blah?a=1
```

Now this is an application that has been in existence for a number of years and URL's are built up either in code behind, directly in aspx files - basically everywhere. Added to the mix is that although an ASPX application it is configured for routing using `System.Web.Routing`. So we might also have:

**without trailing slash in definition**

```
 aRoutes.MapPageRoute("routeBrandsCamp",
                "brand/{name}/camp",
                "~/Pages/Brand/Camp.aspx", true, new RouteValueDictionary
                {
                    {"name", " "}
                });

aRoutes.MapPageRoute("routeBrandsSummary",
            "brand/{name}/summary/",
            "~/Pages/Brand/Summary.aspx", true, new RouteValueDictionary
            {
                {"name", " "}
            });
```

So the solution then seems to be that I need to add a rewrite rule in IIS or should I do something in in say `BeginRequest()`?

Whatever the solution can you also provide a working example? eg. IIS rewrite rule, some code etc.

Basically I want to change this in one place and not break the application ;-)

Comment: Do you want to remove forward slash from the end of the URL?

Comment: Yes.... Did you see the list of url's I provided as examples?

Answer (score 2):

IIS Rewrite Module reserves a node under `system.webServer` section and allow us to configure the settings there pretty easily.

Add the following code under `system.webServer` node :

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>

    <!--To always remove trailing slash from the URL-->
    <rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)/$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}" />
    </rule>

  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

More reference [here](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/remove-trailing-slash-from-the-urls-of-your-asp-net-web-site-with-iis-7-url-rewrite-module),[creating rewrite modules](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)